# Send stepper to position and back AccelStepper

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

At the moment I am working on a code that should send a plateau to a certain position and back. The plateau is being moved by the stepper. My goal is to press '4' on the keyboard and that then the steppers moves to a certain position. However, I am not succeding in this. I am using AccelStepper and at the moment I have the following code:

```
#include <AccelStepper.h>

AccelStepper stepper(1, 5, 4);

int spd = 1000;    // The current speed in steps/second
int sign = 1;      // Either 1, 0 or -1

int buttonState = 0;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  stepper.setMaxSpeed(1000);
  stepper.setSpeed(1000);
}

void loop()
{
  char c;
  if (Serial.available()) {
    c = Serial.read();
    if (c == 'f') {  // forward
      sign = 1;
    }
    if (c == 'r') {  // reverse
      sign = -1;
    }
    if (c == 's') {  // stop
      sign = 0;
    }
    if (c == '1') {  // super slow
      spd = 100;
    }
    if (c == '2') {  // medium
      spd = 900;
    }
    if (c == '3') {  // fast
      spd = 1000;
    }
    if (c == '4') {
      //not working, does anyone know how to do this?
      stepper.moveTo(500);
    }
    stepper.setSpeed(sign * spd);
  }
  stepper.runSpeed();
}
```

Does anyone have tips or know how to achieve this?

Thanks is advance!

Comment: Your question could be better answered in the dedicated Arduino forum (http://arduino.stackexchange.com/) When asking this kind of question, do a drawing of the circuit, or take pictures of your project, we need to know if the wiring is correct... [Also, if your "stepper" is this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepper_motor), then you need check the library that came with it, on how to import/use them (also reffered to as API)

Comment: When you set the position of the stepper (what 500 does it means?) with stepper.moveTo(), that function also set speed to 0?

Comment: Thanks for the tips Bonatti! I looked it up: "Caution: moveTo() also recalculates the speed for the next step. If you are trying to use constant speed movements, you should call setSpeed() after calling moveTo()."       I have also tried it as: stepper.moveTo(500); spd = 1000; , however this is also not working